# Is there any alternative to sill replacement?

Tags: sill

If my house needs sill (plates) replaced, is there any alternative to full replacement? Could I just cut 2x8s and use structural screws to hold it to the old sill to make sure the floors are secure?

My house is post and beam, so the studs do almost nothing.

Comment: Why do they need replacement?

Comment: Sill plates or bottom wall (sole) plates? "Host"? Please edit to clarify and better describe the problem.

Comment: "Host" is presumably an autocorrect failure for misspelled "house".

Comment: If the sill is rotten and left in place, wouldn't the rot invade the subfloor, the bottom plates, the studs?

Comment: What are the bases of the "posts" resting on? Are the bottom ends of the posts directly on a masonry or poured concrete foundation? Or are the bottoms of the posts on the sills? Even if the posts are directly on the masonry whatever process is responsible for rotting the sills could be affecting the posts too. You need to stop this somehow.

Comment: Uh I dont know the technical terms. I'm referring to the beam laying directly ontop the foundation. The foundation is fieldstone

Comment: The rot is from water. Most of it is pretty old, I don't think its still got a big water problem cause the outside is sealed now.